# Testing date/time based behavior in React Native Detox

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

Are there guidelines on testing date/time based behavior with Detox in a React Native app? I have an app whose functionality is largely based on the passing of time. For example, if a user completes a lesson on one day, and then revisits the app on the following day, the user should expect some specific content. What is the best way to update the data/time within the flow of the Detox test? Is this possible?